# Rails field_for partial with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Clasification` that has two `Category`. Each category has `words`. I'm making a `form_for @clasification` and there you can modify it and its `categories` and their respective `words`, using two nested `fields_for`.

The screen is composed of the clasification fields, plus two lists (the categories) filled up with items (words). There, you can drag and drop items between lists to assign them to another one.

I need to have a "new item" button and I thought of rendering a blank `Word` in a third column and then drop it into the desired `Category`, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

The drag and drop functionality is based on the `SortableJS` library.

Here's my code.

**_word.html.slim**

```
= builder.fields_for :words, builder.object.words do |word_builder|
  .clasification-word
    = word_builder.text_field :word, placeholder: "Texto"
    = word_img(word_builder.object)
    = word_builder.hidden_field :category_id
    = word_builder.hidden_field :_destroy*
```

**form.html.slim**

```
.dialogo-main
  = form_for [@book, @clasification], remote: true do |f|
    .dialogo-content
      .column.column--left
        = f.text_field :title, placeholder: true, class: 'clasification-title-input'
        = f.text_area :description, placeholder: true, class: 'clasification-description-input'
        = f.fields_for :result do |fff|
          = fff.number_field :score, placeholder: true, class: 'clasification-score-input'
      .column.column--right
        .clasification-categories
        = f.fields_for :categories, @clasification.categories do |ff|
          .clasification-categories
            = ff.text_field :name, placeholder: true, class: 'clasification-category-input'
            = ff.hidden_field :id
            .clasification-list
              = render 'word', builder: ff
    .dialogo-buttons
      = f.submit class: ['btn', 'btn-primary']
      button.btn.btn-default.dialogo-button-cancelar type='button' data-dismiss='modal' Cancelar

javascript:
  $categorias = $('.clasification-list');
  for(var i = 0; i < $categorias.size(); i++){
    var elem = $categorias[i];
    Sortable.create(elem, {
      group: {
        name: 'categories',
        pull: function (to, from) {
          var elements = from.el.getElementsByClassName('clasification-word');
          return elements.length > 1;
        },
        put: function(to) {
          var elements = to.el.getElementsByClassName('clasification-word');
          return elements.length < 7;
        }
      },
      onAdd: function(evt){
        var item = evt.item;
        var nuevaCategoriaId = $(item.parentNode.parentNode).find('input[type=hidden]')[0].value
        console.log(nuevaCategoriaId);
        $(item).find('input[type=hidden]')[0].value = nuevaCategoriaId;
      }
    });
  }
```